# get the first number in string if there is one

Tags: php, string

I am looking for a way to extract the first number out of a string. This examples

```
    43
    432Phill 21
    432hill 21
    43#1 Example
    43,123 example
```

should return

```
    43
    432
    432
    43
    43,123
```

I assume it would be possible to use `strpos` and iterate needle from a-z, A-Z and #. to get all positions and than use the lowest non-zero one to determine the point where number ends. This seems like an overkill. Is there a better way of doing it ?

EDIT: the position is to use substr later. If there is a better way I am down with it.

Comment: If you need to extract the first number from the string then update the question's title. Now it is misleading and contradicts the question.

Comment: As above, do you want the number, or the position. And is you example data one string, or 5?

Comment: You get the fastest way to do that. Other than that you can use regex to check your variable as well if you don't want to use your own solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number starts at begining you can do this like this:

```
$number = floatval($string); //it will return float e.g. 432
```

If you use comma instead of decimal point e.g. 43,123 you must first replace it with dot:

```
$string = str_replace(',', '.', '43,123 example');
```

Comment: The OP is not looking for the float value of the whole string. He just wants the number at the beginning of each string.

Answer (score 3):

With a regex, you can extract numbers from a string.

The following statement should do the trick:
`preg_match_all('~\d+~', $string, $match);`

`$match` is the array of the numbers contained in `$string`.